# Why these ormap and for/or functions giving error?

Tags: functional-programming, racket

I am trying to find out if any of the characters in a string is not a printable character `(integer value > 127)`. I tried 2 functions, one with `ormap` and another with `for/or`, but both are not working:

```
(define (isBinary line)
  (for/or ([ch line])
    ((char->integer ch) > 127)))

(define (isBinary2 line)
  (ormap (lambda (ch) ((char->integer ch) > 127)) (string->list line)))

(displayln (isBinary "abcd1234"))
(displayln (isBinary2 "abcd1234"))
```

Both give same error:

```
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: 97
  arguments...:
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike other languages where `>` is the name on an operator, in Racket `>` is a name  of a normal function. To compare two numbers write `(< a b)` which is the standard way of using `<`.

For those that like infix notation, Racket also provides an not often used syntax:

```
(a . < . b)
```

which will by the reader be turned into

```
(< a b)
```